# How to aggregate between two dates in R?

Tags: r, date, aggregate

Below are the two tables

```
Table1
Date                   OldPrice   NewPrice
2014-06-12 09:32:56       0          10
2014-06-27 16:13:36       10         12
2014-08-12 22:41:47       12         13

Table2
Date                   Qty
2014-06-15 18:09:23     5
2014-06-19 12:04:29     4
2014-06-22 13:21:34     3
2014-06-29 19:01:22     6
2014-07-01 18:02:33     3
2014-09-29 22:41:47     6
```

I want to display the result in this manner

```
Date                   OldPrice   NewPrice    Qty
2014-06-12 09:32:56       0          10        0
2014-06-27 16:13:36       10         12        12
2014-08-12 22:41:47       12         13        15
```

I used the command

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Table1)){

  startDate = Table1$Date[i]
  endDate = Table1$Date[i+1]


 code=aggregate(list(Table2$Qty),
by=list(Table1$Date, Table1$OldPrice, Table1$NewPrice, Date = Table2$Date > startDate  & Table2$Date <= endDate), FUN=sum)

}
```

I want the quantity to be aggregated between the given dates in first table, i.e between the first and second dates, second and third dates and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1)[df2, roll = -Inf, on = .(Date)][, .(Qty = sum(Qty)),
           .(OldPrice, NewPrice)][df1, on = .(OldPrice, NewPrice)][is.na(Qty), Qty := 0]
setcolorder(res, c(names(df1), "Qty"))
res
#                   Date OldPrice NewPrice Qty
#1: 2014-06-12 09:32:56        0       10   0
#2: 2014-06-27 16:13:36       10       12  12
#3: 2014-08-12 22:41:47       12       13   9
```

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                            
 unused arguments (roll = -Inf, on = .("Date"))

Comment: @VarunJayaram  I assumed the 'Date' objects are `POSIXct` class

Comment: @VarunJayaram  I am not getting any error.  I used `data.table_1.10.5` .  what is your data.table version?

Comment: its 1.10.4.3... I'm using RStudio

Comment: @VarunJayaram  I noticed that I forgot to use the `setDT` to convert to data.table`.  Fixed it.  Can you try now

Comment: @VarunJayaram  I provided the answer for your original question.  New questions, please post as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072338/how-to-aggregate-between-the-two-dates-in-r    Please provide the solution @akrun

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093414/how-to-convert-into-hms-format-from-mmss-0-in-r .... Will you be able to help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit verbose idea with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_join(Table1, Table2, by = "Date") %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  fill(OldPrice, NewPrice, .direction = "up") %>% 
  group_by(OldPrice, NewPrice) %>% 
  summarize(Qty = sum(Qty, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Qty) %>% 
  bind_cols(Table1, .)

#                  Date OldPrice NewPrice Qty
# 1 2014-06-12 09:32:56        0       10   0
# 2 2014-06-27 16:13:36       10       12  12
# 3 2014-08-12 22:41:47       12       13   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You started with a for loop hence you could do the following the for loops way:

```
df1 <- read.table(text=
"'Date'                   'OldPrice'   'NewPrice'
'2014-06-12 09:32:56'     '0'          '10'
'2014-06-27 16:13:36'     '10'         '12'
'2014-08-12 22:41:47'     '12'         '13'", stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)

df2 <- read.table(text=
"'Date'                  'Qty'
'2014-06-15 18:09:23'     '5'
'2014-06-19 12:04:29'     '4'
'2014-06-22 13:21:34'     '3'
'2014-06-29 19:01:22'     '6'
'2014-07-01 18:02:33'     '3'" , stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)

df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(Date)),] #order df1 by Date
df1$Date <- as.POSIXct(df1$Date); df2$Date <- as.POSIXct(df2$Date) #convert into datetime formats
values <- vector("list", length = nrow(df1)) #declare a list of specific length of df1

for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){
  if(df2$Date[j]>df1$Date[i] & df2$Date[j]<df1$Date[i+1]){
    values[[i]] <- append(values[[i]], df2$Qty[j])
  }
  }
}

df1$Quantity <- c(0, sapply(values, sum)[1:(nrow(df1)-1)]) #replace the leading quantity value with 0 (as per your example)

#                 Date OldPrice NewPrice Quantity
#1 2014-06-12 09:32:56        0       10        0
#2 2014-06-27 16:13:36       10       12       12
#3 2014-08-12 22:41:47       12       13        9
```

Obviously, more work, but it could help out if you were stuck on for loops.